# "E: File does not exist: file" while removing a package

Tags: dpkg

I decided to shift around my partitions on my hard drive for a fresh install of Kubuntu.
I booted my Ubuntu 10.10 live disc, shifted everything around and attempted to install grub and it didn't work, so I burnt an Ubuntu 12.04 disc and installed it.

I got the computer working and wanted to install some packages, but didn't have an internet connection at the time.  So (I know this was stupid) I got some debs from previous versions of Ubuntu, as I needed my music, and the other install took a long of time to boot.

Once I got my internet connection back, everything worked ok, for a little while.  Then I stumbled upon this problem after removing ten broken packages using synaptic:

```
drhax@Spamotard:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libgtk2.0-cil
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 417 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 2,638 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 103052 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libgtk2.0-cil ...
E: File does not exist: /usr/share/cli-common/packages.d/policy.2.6.gtk-dotnet.installcligac
dpkg: error processing libgtk2.0-cil (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgtk2.0-cil
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Help would be appreciated.  This is my first post, but I do know fair bit about Ubuntu, so feel free to point out any stupid mistakes I have made.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all libgtk2.0-cil
```

Was not enough for me I had to :

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgtk2.0-cil.postrm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgtk2.0-cil.postrm.tmp

sudo dpkg -P --force-all libgtk2.0-cil
```

I renamed other files but it may not be needed :

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgtk2.0-cil.clilibs.tmp
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgtk2.0-cil.md5sums.tmp
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgtk2.0-cil.postrm.tmp
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgtk2.0-cil.list.tmp
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgtk2.0-cil.postinst.tmp
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgtk2.0-cil.prerm.tmp
```

-- 
http://rzr.online.fr/q/dpkg

Comment: You are my saviour! It worked like a charm. I thought that I had trashed my installation because of a similiar issue.

Answer (score 4):

Force the package removal with: `sudo dpkg -P --force-all libgtk2.0-cil`.

Comment: This post is a bit old, but if this is happening, please also file a bug against libgtk2.0-cil

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found an answer. If you're getting a `File doesn't exist` error, you can just create an empty file where it needs to be in order to remove the package.

For example, `sudo touch /usr/share/cli-common/packages.d/policy.2.6.gtk-dotnet.installcligac`.

When the postrm script runs, the file you created will be removed.

Comment: yes I had this error when I deleted the files before uninstalling them, so I temporarily restored them